# How to access AppSettings in Startup class constructor in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm trying to add SeriLog settings like min log level and rolling file path from a config file.  The standard is to hard code them like this:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.RollingFile("C:/LogFiles/log-{Date}.txt")
        .CreateLogger();
}
```

Basically, I need to be able to access values from appsettings.json in the Startup constructor.  Something like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Is((LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogEventLevel),
        Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings.MinimumLoggingLevel")))
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings.RollingFilePath"))
```

I found the `Configuration.GetValue` syntax in another SO post, but it always returns `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if `AppSettings` section is like this:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "RollingFilePath": "..."
},
```

then change `.` to `:`

```
.WriteTo.RollingFile(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:RollingFilePath"))
```

or use this one

```
.WriteTo.RollingFile(Configuration["AppSettings:RollingFilePath"])
```

Answer (score 3):

My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
   "Logging": {
   "IncludeScopes": false,
   "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
   }
}
```

To access a value I can just use something like this:

```
var IncludeScopes = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Logging:IncludeScopes", true);
```